# How to show text and image in bottom toolbar of a scene in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to replace the bar button items in my toolbar with images. I was able to select image in the attribute inspector. But now the text is replaced with image. Is there anyway i can keep both text and image (text should be below image)

What i have is this. 
[Please click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4wLq.png)

What i am looking for is something like this
[Please click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF9gH.png)

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the image in the selected image attribute
And you can place the text in the bar item title attribute
Something like this [image: Here is the image]

This can be done when you do to the navigation controller for that particular tab.. Like in your case navigation controller for item 1
Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks ! I am using XCode 7 and the moment i enter the Title value, the Image property value goes away and vice versa. Looks like they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ohok.. The one I am implementing on in xcode 7.1 .. Maybe you could try upgrading

Comment: Thanks ! I was not using Tab bar controller. I had my buttons on the toolbar !